# ¿Como crear un subproceso en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy escribiendo un código pero no me ha funcionado como es esperado. Una versión simplificada del código és así:

```
from subprocess import call
import time

call([r"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"])
time.sleep(5)
call(["taskkill", "/im", "notepad.exe"])
```

Al rodar el script arriba, el código no corre desde la línea del primer `call`, o sea, el script abre el notepad y se queda esperando una respuesta de `call([r"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"])`, pero esto solo ocurre cuando yo manualmente cierro el notepad.

Me gustaria que el script abriera el notepad, espere 5 segundos y lo cierre, sin intervención manual del usuário. Entonces, ¿como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar `Popen` en vez de `call`:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')
```

La función [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) espera a que el comando se complete, es por eso que te retorna el control de ejecución cuando cierras el `notepad.exe`.

La función [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) es ejecutado en un proceso nuevo (hijo).

Luego del `sleep`, puedes usar la función [`Popen.kill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) para terminar el proceso:

```
import subprocess
import time

process = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe')
time.sleep(5)
process.kill()
```

Si deseas interactuar con el subproceso usando `Popen` (enviar datos al `stdin`, leer del `stdout` o `stderr`), puedes usar la función [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('C:\comando.exe')
print 'Durante el proceso'
stdout, stderr = process.communicate() # Esperando
print 'Fin del proceso'
```

Pero ten en cuenta que `Popen.communicate` espera la finalización del subproceso, por lo tanto, ya no es necesario usar `Popen.kill`

Comment: ¿Ya que tengo el `process`, como retorno del `Popen`, puedo usarlo para matar específicamente la ventana que he abierto?

Comment: @Math mira mi actualización

Comment: ¡Excelente!​​​​

Comment: Ok, pero ahora creo que tengo que cambiar el título de mi pregunta, jajaja.. Estaba seguro que necesitaría de threads

Comment: @Math creo que bastaría con que cambies "thread" por "subproceso"